# From one JS calculator to three JS calculators on one page using new Calculator

Tags: javascript

I created one working JavaScript Calculator and now I want to have 3 calc on one page like this:

using:

`const calculator1 = new Calculator("calculator1");
const calculator2 = new Calculator("calculator2");
const calculator3 = new Calculator("calculator3");`

But all the buttons from 3 calculators work only with first calculator. What did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: Because you are using duplicate id values in different html elements. Except calculate1..3, change all ids to classes, and change in the js code where you use them.

Comment: There are different problems. The most important thing is the understanding that once you introduce globals to your OO object, they are no longer reusable. Your calculator function should take the root node to be used, and run queries findings the elements it needs only within that element instead of querying the full document (which is where you were using globals)

Comment: Thanks guys! I will try to find working solution using your tips!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because all the calculators are using the same variable (not sure, I'm new to js and just looked over it quickly) but the easiest solution to your problem that I can think of is to put the calculators in s so they don't interact with each other. Also, it's never a good idea to put the name of the Calculator() the same as the ID of the  you put it in. Maybe that will help.